# Use xonsh to loop over files with ls

Tags: xonsh

I want to use xonsh to bzip several files in a directory.  I first attempt this with the following:

```
$ ls
table_aa.csv    table_amgn.csv  table_csco.csv  table_esrx.csv  table_hal.csv  table_jbl.csv  table_pcg.csv   table_zmh.csv
table_aapl.csv  table_amzn.csv  table_d.csv     table_gas.csv   table_hp.csv   table_jpm.csv  table_usb.csv
$ for fn in ls:
..    bzip2 fn
..
NameError: name 'ls' is not defined
```

OK, so I use `$()` explicitly

```
$ for fn in $(ls).split():
.     bzip2 fn
bzip2: Can't open input file fn: No such file or directory.
bzip2: Can't open input file fn: No such file or directory.
```

Is there a better way to do this?

```
$ xonsh --version
('xonsh/0.3.4',)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are very close with the second example.  The only thing to note is that `fn` is a Python variable name, so you have to use `@()` to pass it to a subprocess:

`$ for fn in $(ls).split():
.     bzip2 @(fn)`

Also, on v0.3.4, you could use regex globbing instead of ls,

`` $ for fn in `.*`:
.     bzip2 @(fn) ``

And at least on master, you can now iterate through !() line-by-line, which means that the following will also work if you are wedded to ls:

`$ for fn in !(ls):
.     bzip2 @(fn)`

Answer (score 2):

Using `ls`:

```
for fn in !(ls):
    print(fn.rstrip())
```

Using globs (available in regex, shell, and path varieties):

```
for fn in g`*`:
    print(fn)
```

Using Python APIs (see the os, glob, or pathlib modules):

```
import os
for fn in os.listdir():
    print(fn)
```

Comment: the reminder to just use Python is really helpful. It's hard to get out of the shell mindset when you're used to being stuck in it.

I've decided to `import os` inside my .xonshrc so that it's already available whenever I want to use it.